# Ruby 1.9.3 vs Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering as to what are the pros and cons of working with Ruby 1.9.3 and Ruby 2.0.0 with respect to the Rails environment in production. What benefits one has over the other in terms of syntax, language features, online-documentation, community support, etc.

Comment: Ruby is not Python or C. You use most recent version, safe for rare situations when gem you need is not compatibile with it. There are no advantages of old Rubies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.3 is past End of Life and no longer receiving updates:

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/02/23/support-for-ruby-1-9-3-has-ended/

You should no longer use this on any projects.

Use the newest version of Ruby you possibly can - the current version is Ruby 2.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Take the latest version, unless you are limited by an old project.
You will have the latest features and security updates.
Of course don't go for the edge. But the latest stable version.
Security updates for 1.9.3 ended.
[Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/01/10/ruby-1-9-3-will-end-on-2015/)
2.0.0 security maintenance will end on feb 2016.
Go for 2.2.x, you'll have more time.

Comment: Why? Can you list the reasons?

Answer (score 1):

This site has some benchmarks http://www.isrubyfastyet.com

You should always use the latest stable version imho.

Answer (score 1):

There are several benefits when using more recent versions of Ruby:

- Security (e.g. old versions might have unfixed issues) and maintenance
- Compatibility with gems you want to use (e.g. current versions might use kwargs that were introduced in Ruby 2.0)
- Performance (newer versions are usually faster, see [source](http://www.isrubyfastyet.com))
- Documentation and learning (it might be harder to find solutions to problems or good blog articles for old versions)

That said: Try to keep up-to-date and use the most recent version that is supported by your environment and dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. But, aren't these too broad.